# How to extend Silex Doctrine MySQL query library?

Tags: php, doctrine, silex, extends

As the title says, I'm using Silex and Doctrine. Though, I'd like to use some of my own simple classes to extend Doctrine. But I don't know what to put after 'extends ....?'. This is an example of how I would extend doctrine:

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

And this one:

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .= '?';
        if ($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, to create an external class that extends Doctrine. What would my class look like:

> class DB extends ... {
>
> //blablabla
>
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom entity repositories ([Symfony example is  crystal clear on this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)) Your can see you must extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`

Inside your custom entity repository you need to create your methods by using one of the following methods:

- [EntityRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php) methods: findBy, findOneBy, etc (simplest but limited)
- [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) (almost SQL but with steroids)
- [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) (nice OOP API)
- [NativeSQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) (worst option)

You need to start thinking the ORM way and not the old concatenate-strings-to-form-my-insecure-sql way ;)